# Как перебором списка назначить разные функции на Button в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, tkinter, button

```
import tkinter


w = tkinter.Tk()
lst = ['Hello', 'World']

def prt(i):
    print(i)

for i in lst:
    b = tkinter.Button(master=w, text=i, command=prt(i))
    b.pack()

w.mainloop()
```

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при переборе списка для каждого его элемента создавалась кнопка с текстом элемента списка, а потом этот же элемент передавался в функцию, привязанную к кнопке и при нажатии на кнопку выполнялась функция?

При выполнении кода появляется окошко с двумя кнопками, в консоли сразу выполняются функции, при нажатии на кнопки ничего не происходит.

Пробовал обращаться через индекс элемента:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
```

результат тот же.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter

w = tkinter.Tk()
lst = ['Hello', 'World']

def prt(i):
    print(i)
    
for i in lst:
# +++                                            vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv  <----
    b = tkinter.Button(master=w, text=i, command=lambda i=i: prt(i))
    b.pack()
    
w.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Функции в python это "полноправные граждане" - игра слов при переводе с английского "functions are a first-class type" - "functions are first class citizens". C ними вы можете делать все, что и строками, цифрами, колекциями. То есть составлять из них списки, отправлять их как аргументы в другие функции и т. д.

```
import tkinter

w = tkinter.Tk()
lst = ['Hello', 'World']
btns = []


def prt1():
    print(lst[0])


def prt2():
    print(lst[1])

# Здесь мы пробегаемся по кортежу из функций.
for i, prt in enumerate((prt1, prt2)):
    b = tkinter.Button(master=w, text=lst[i], command=prt)
    b.pack()
    btns.append(b) # сохраняем кнопки в список,
                   # чтобы к ним можно было бы в будущем обратиться.
print(btns)
w.mainloop()
```

Даже объект "кнопка" подчиняется "законодательству" Pytnon. Я сохранил их в списке, хотя удобней было бы в словаре с ключом по имени соответствующей функции. Но это уже другая история...

```
[<tkinter.Button object .!button>, <tkinter.Button object .!button2>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту задачу через DataFrame.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
```

---

создаем кортежи данных

```
rows = ('0', '0', '1', '1') 
columns = ('0', '1', '0', '1')
buttons = ('7', '8', '9', '/')
```

---

формирую данные в массив

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'btn': buttons, 'r': rows, 'c': columns})
```

---

```
ap = Tk()
ap.title('as')
```

---

создаем простейший цикл, в котором значения присваиваются по индексу массива, данные которого очень легко редактировать.

```
for index in range(len(df)):  
    b = Button(ap, text=df['btn'][index]) 
    b.grid(row=df['r'][index], column=df['c'][index])
```

---

```
ap.mainloop()
```

При запуске мы получим программу с 4-мя кнопками, расположенными по сетке в 2 ряда и 2 колонки и у которых уже есть присвоенное значение. Кнопкам можно присваивать нужную команду. На эти кнопки можно повесить одну команду и управлять через условие if-elif-else